# Application (puddletag) can not open files from second drive, only files located at /home/user/*

Tags: partitioning, permissions, mount, hard-drive

I reached the most frustrating point and coulnd't find anywhere in the web an answer so I hope, this could be here my last possibility for a solution.

**Situation:** I want to edit mp3 tags with a program- my mp3 files are on my 2nd HDD, but if I want to open files from there into the program- just nothing happen. Only if I copied the file to **/home/user/music**, then it work immediately.

I don't know whats wrong ...
I think, it could be a problem with the rights/permissions? The second drive is NTFS drive (was used in windows also as second drive), the primary drive (SSD) is formated by ubuntu, so not NTFS I guess. I changed after some web research the mounting line for this drive like following, because I hoped it could help:

@/etc/fstab:

> /dev/sda2 /media/DRIVEMOUNTDIRECTORY ntfs-3g uid=1000,gid=1000,noauto,user 0 0

If I click now on properties of a random file on this drive, it says user and group are me/mine, as configured (1000). But I still can not import it into the program :( Im really sad, because I can not believe that this little problem is making me stuck with linux now :(

Bevor I did anything to the fstab file, it was something like this:

> /dev/disk/by-uuid/F4AA07random/mnt/F4AA07random auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0

Do you have an idea, what I could do? It is because my primary ssd is about ~250GB and my 2nd drive is 4TB, and thats why I did not take all my personal data into the /home/user/media-folders

P.S: I also just changed one file on the HDD with sudo chmod 000 filename but still it stays with permissions -rwxrwxrwx like all the other files; so changing permissions here doesn't seem to help :( The program just ... don't want to work with the file, even if I'm declared as owner...

P.P.S: If I try to load out of the program a file, the program doesn't seem to see the drive at /media/DRIVEMOUNTDIRECTORY  but at /home/*somewhere he is able it import ... o.O

Using Ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out that this program (puddletag) just had access problems- it seems, that the program can not handle NTFS partitions or idk... now I'm using (a for me better mp3 tag editor) kid3 and there are no problems- easy accessing all drives and all folders. Perfect :)