# Puddletag-snap can't see files on NTFS drives

Tags: 18.04, 20.04, snap

I'm having the same problem as in this post, which was marked "solved" without a real solution:
[Application (puddletag) can not open files from second drive, only files located at /home/user/* (solved)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1320732/application-puddletag-can-not-open-files-from-second-drive-only-files-located).

Puddletag works fine on Ubuntu 18.04 (dual boot on same PC), but now that I'm running 20.04 with MATE 1.24.0 I can only find puddletag-snap and it doesn't see the same files on the same computer as before. It does see files on my home drive, however, so I'm inclined to think the same is happening as in the previous post.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Really puddletag-snap does not have access to removable media, there is no such plug in its [manifest file](https://gitlab.com/tschlaeppi/puddletag-snap/-/blob/master/snap/snapcraft.yaml). You have to ask Snap developer to add it.

So you have two options:

- use puddletag 1.2 from [official repository](https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/bionic/puddletag) on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS  by

  ```
  sudo add-apt-repository universe
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get install puddletag
  ```
- use puddletag 2.x from [PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Esavoury1/+archive/ubuntu/multimedia/+packages?field.name_filter=puddletag&field.status_filter=published&field.series_filter=focal) on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (package for 18.04 LTS also [exists](https://launchpad.net/%7Esavoury1/+archive/ubuntu/multimedia/+packages?field.name_filter=puddletag&field.status_filter=published&field.series_filter=bionic)) by

  ```
  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:savoury1/multimedia
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get install puddletag
  ```

Comment: Downloading puddletag 2.0.1 for Ubuntu 20.04 from the savoury1 PPA, as described above by @N0rbert totally solved this issue for me. Many thanks.